# Can we report something without following the rules of reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

> My girlfriend said that she loves me very much but after we broke up she said that she doesn't want me.

Is the sentence correct? If I need to explain the exact meaning, do I need to  change the tense as per the rule of reported speech or can keep it without changing tense?

Answer (score 1):

One's first response is to change *doesn't want me* to "didn't want me".

However, if your sentence is stating a continuing truth - your girlfriend continues to reject you - it's correct to keep the present tense in reported speech.

The situation changes if after your girlfriend rejected you, she might have regretted her words and tried to make up. In that case, at the time *she said that she didn't want you*. In this context you need the past tense.

Comment: What about the first three lines.and if I want to say the exact meaning of the situation then if we dont change the tense then that will be be right and changing tense changes the meaning too

Comment: My girlfriend said that she loves me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct.  It puts her statement in the past, where it occurred, but keeps the content of the statement in the past's present, which it was, then.

It also, because of the way we go beyond the information given, implies that the "doesn't" is still true now.  Had it been "didn't want me", the current situation would be undefined without more information.

Comment: Which one is correct you said.keeping the content of the statement in the past's present is not according to the rules of the reporting speech.So is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing phrasing!  Yes, it is grammatically correct.  Она сказала, что меня больше не любит is exactly the same construction (apologies if you're not a russophone).

Comment: Sorry for asking several times can you please say the name of the rule if it is not the rule of reporting speech.actually I need it for some reference

Comment: To be honest, I don't know whether there is a special rule involved.  There are a lot of *general*, social-domain, rules, such as Don't Deceive Your Listener, that cover things like not using unqualified past time for things that did not take place in the past, but the rules for reporting speech are 1) if you're quoting, use the exact syntax and vocabulary used by the quotee; or 2) if you're not actually quoting, paraphrase accurately unless you have some socially-acceptable reason not to do it, e.g. substituting present tense for the sake of immediacy.

Comment: I just re-read your example statement, and it seems that there might be some unintentional ambiguity.  This time, I read it as perhaps meaning "she says she [still] loves me, but since the breakup isn't interested in a sexual relationship with me"

Comment: I couldnt get it .

Comment: "My girlfriend said that she loves me very much but after we broke up she said that she doesn't want me."   It's ambiguous.  There are 2 possible interpretations:  she loved you before the breakup but doesn't love you now, or she still loves you but doesn't want (to continue?) a sexual relationship with you.  To resolve the ambiguity, we need to know whether the first "she said" happened before or after the breakup.  So if you need to "explain the exact meaning", you have to supply more information or alter the form, e.g. "My gf used to love me but since the breakup she doesn't want me".